# How to register ResolverInterceptors with SPQR and Spring

Tags: java, graphql-spqr

I am trying to create some authentication mechanism for my spring-boot/graphQL/SPQR-project. I managed to do it on a single service method via @GraphQLRootContext  annotation:

```
@GraphQLMutation(name = "createProblem")
public Problem createProblem(
        @GraphQLRootContext DefaultGlobalContext<Object> context,
        @GraphQLArgument(name = "problemInput") @Valid Problem problemInput)
{ 
    WebRequest request = (WebRequest) context.getNativeRequest();
    String token = request.getHeader("token");
}
```

here I can extract a JWT token and verify/validate it.
However, I want to do that on a global level without having to add the context parameter to all of my methods. 
I am trying to implement a ResolverInterceptor as described [here](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/blob/graphql-spqr-v0.9.9/src/test/java/io/leangen/graphql/InterceptorTest.java#L34).

However, I don't know how to register this Interceptor with the spring application, so that it is invoked properly. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance, Matthias

Answer (score 4):

I'd whole-heartedly suggest you use existing Spring features for handling security instead of rolling out your own, as it already has everything you need to process JWT. Since SPQR will invoke Spring-managed beans, all Spring features will work normally.

If that's for some reason not an option, yes, `ResolverInterceptor` is the way to go, as it can intercept any resolver invocation and inspect the root context.

For your case, if you want a `ResolverInterceptor` that is applicable globally (to all resolvers), you can use `GlobalResolverInterceptorFactory`:

```
@Bean
public ExtensionProvider<GeneratorConfiguration, ResolverInterceptorFactory> customInterceptors() {
    return (config, interceptors) -> interceptors.append(new GlobalResolverInterceptorFactory(customGlobalInterceptors);
}
```

If you want to optimize a bit and intercept some resolvers only e.g. based on an annotation, you can provide a custom `ResolverInterceptorFactory` like:

```
public class AuthInterceptorFactory implements ResolverInterceptorFactory {

    List<ResolverInterceptor> authInterceptor = Collections.singletonList(new AuthInterceptor());

    @Override
    public List<ResolverInterceptor> getInterceptors(ResolverInterceptorFactoryParams params) {
        return params.getResolver().getTypedElement().isAnnotationPresent(Auth.class) ? authInterceptor : Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Inside of your `ResolverInterceptor` if the token in missing or invalid, you want to throw an `AbortExecutionException` to prevent further execution.

Comment: I'm registering my customInterceptor in a kotlin Spring Boot app and am getting type mismatch errors with the lambda function: `return { config, interceptors -> interceptors.append(GlobalResolverInterceptorFactory(customGlobalInterceptors)) }`. Any idea on how to fix this @kaqqao?

Comment: @AdlyThebaud I've never used Kotlin, but if it doesn't like the lambda there, you can always explicitly create an instance of `ExtensionProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! What would that look like in Java? Also, where would I get the `GeneratorConfiguration` from?